# Insert rows of states and iso's from comma separated textfile into webbased Mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, load-data-infile

I'm building an international webshop and in the part where a customer has to fill in the address I wonder how I insert the rows in a comma separated text file with a list of stats in my web based MySQL?
Example

```
AM,04,"Geghark'unik'"
AM,05,"Kotayk'"
AM,06,"Lorri"
AM,07,"Shirak"
AM,08,"Syunik'"
AM,09,"Tavush"
AM,10,"Vayots' Dzor"
```

I found the whole list here : http://www.maxmind.com/app/fips_include
There's a "File to import" page but I get errors while including the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MySQL's [LOAD DATA INFILE functionality](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).